# ASP.net MVC: PK and FK values are not in sync on lazy loading for one-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have the tables Company and Roles with one-to-many relation. I know that for lazy loading set-up the FK value of a Role entity should be automatically set to be in sync with his PK value of a Company. In the Company table I have a company entity instance added, but for some reason it is added null when I add a new role entity instance. What am I doing wrong?

These are my domain classes and the context:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        RoleOverviews = new List<RoleOverview>();
    }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RoleOverview> RoleOverviews { get; set; }

}

public class AppDbContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleOverview> RoleOverviews { get; set; }
    public AppDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RoleId,Name,Description")] Role role)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Roles.Add(role);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "CompaniesRolesMV");
    }

    return View(role);
}
```

Comment: 'For some reason it is added null' ? You haven't clearly explained what the issue is and where you are encountering it.

Comment: yes sorry, when I add a new role I should get the FK value from the PK value of the Company table, but instead I get null in the Roles table. The PK and the FK should be in sync when added a new entity in the child table, in my case Role table.

Comment: I thought its the other way around. You add a new entry in the PK table and then add it again in the FK table

Comment: could you show the Role adding code?
since we cant see the table definitions it's hard to say for certain but the way your classes are set up it indicated that the relationship you defined is that Roles are a child table: hence, they have to be 'told' which Company they 'Belong' to

Comment: Yes. The RolesController is the scaffolded one. Nothing changed! I will add it now!

Comment: the Role you are defining/creating in your 'Create' method needs to have a CompanyID value supplied. Presumably, the user will have a choice from a Selector ?

Comment: As I was saying the: The PK_FK relationship you have defined will only make certain that the company field in your Role table will have a valid ID. but it cannot 'guess' which company it belongs to unless the code tells it.

Comment: I know this, but I asked a teacher of mine and he said that if all the conventions are respected should be automatically synced without the user interaction, enforced by the EF. So I have to deal with - adding the value of the FK programmatically myself?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what the teacher has said. I think my earlier comment explains what 'synching' implies

Comment: I understood what you said, that was a reply for your previous comment.

Comment: yes, I figured as much, sorry if I sound heavy handed. Just wanted to make sure... I think you got it. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: @DaniDev Will you post an answer that I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Answer added, sorry I didn't add the company selector code but I think you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PK_FK relationship you have defined will only make certain that the company field in your Role table will have a valid ID. but it cannot 'guess' which company it belongs to unless the code tells it.

the Role you are defining/creating in your 'Create' method needs to have a CompanyID value supplied. Presumably, the user will have a choice from a Selector (?)

you probably need t define a Company selector in your View  and your Create Method Action should include the CompanyID from that selector:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RoleId,Name,Description,CompanyID")] Role role)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Roles.Add(role);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "CompaniesRolesMV");
    }

    return View(role);
}
```